# Applying Textures

Tags: texturing

I am trying to add photo textures to an aircraft hanger for XP11. I used Materialize to create various texture Maps including Ambient Occlusion. There are about 4 variations of the texture Map. Do I apply these individually and bake each one separately or use the saved full Material that includes a combination of all of the various maps

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using, and are you meaning that they are a PBR styled image texture set? If using 2.81 or higher, you should be able to add them in the shader node tree and plug them into the appropriate slots of the Principled BSDF.

Comment: I'm very new to blender and still scratching around. The textures are produced from photos taken at my local airfield, I don't believe they would convert to PBR?

Answer (score 0):

Full material can be used (don't know about AO map - i've heard rumors that there's no need in that one, cause blender will recalculate all on it's own, but i don't have any valuble info on this point), however, keeping textures separated gives you MUCH more control on each one in Node editor, so, it's recommended to keep them separated.